# Can school administration see what I'm browsing on my personal computer at home?

Tags: google-apps

I'm wondering what type of access a school administrator might have to my browsing history/watch while I am working and teaching.

I work from home on my private wi-fi network, and I use my personal device, not a school device while I teach. The only thing I do is sign in to my school's Gmail account for my district access. I don't allow Google to sync and add all of my extensions, however.

Comment: The fact that you are using your own computer and your own internet connection considerably reduces the likelihood that the school that you work for is monitoring your online activity.  Of course, it's not impossible, but the school would have to act egregiously to do so.

Comment: There are dozens of similar questions around. Should be closed and redirected towards one of them.

Comment: I'm trying to interpret your wording. Is your Google account your school/district account or your personal account?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on your own network, it's not likely. The only way they would be able to do that is if they have some sort of management software installed to your computer. Without that, they won't be able to see anything.

Comment: Unless the Gmail accoutn mentioned in the post is administered by the school.

Comment: True, but it appears he has syncing off anyway.

Comment: That's for browser settings, not actual content ...

Comment: I'd say it's unclear. The school would be able to see it if he was signed into the browser with a school account and the browser was configured to sync browser history. His question doesn't make it clear if that's what he means by "I don't allow Google to sync".

Comment: Can users of a Google Business account prevent monitoring if monitoring is configured from the Admin console?